# Equivalent of GOTO in Python exception handling

Tags: python

I will have the following code structure in my Python script. But goto is ugly and not allowed to use in Python.

Could some one can suggest a prettier and more pythonic flow design to accomplish this?

PS:
I tried to use recursive function call in exception handler, but the program ate plenty of memory after a while.

```
try:
    # label: log_in
    login_to_system()
    # label: run
    while True:
        query()
        calculate()
        update()
    # Network exceptions might occur during login and query/update
    # Other exceptions might occur during query/calculate/update but do not need to login again.

except SomeNetworkException:
    # Need to log in to system again
    go to: label log_in
except OtherExceptions:
    go to: label run
```

Updated:

In this case, Network exceptions handler is "shared" by both login and other functions.

Previously, I wrapped login_to_system() function with a try/except block and wrote the same code in login's exception handler, but I felt it was ugly to have the same exception handler code twice in this block.

Comment: Why not just put the exception handling code under the `except`, instead of jumping somewhere else?

Comment: Restructure your code to not need goto; use proper looping instead, and escape from the loop when no longer needed. Move your exception handling closer to where the exception actually needs to be handled.

Comment: I cannot say more as your code sample is too generic for us to be any more specific here.

Comment: Of course there is `goto` in Python, just [`import goto`](http://entrian.com/goto/)!

Comment: @RobertHarvey For example, I can put `foo()` under `except Exception1`, but I am not able to handle the exceptions raised by this `foo()` any more. To reuse the exception handlers, I need to jump back to the try block.

Comment: If you want that, your `try/catch` block needs to be *inside your `while` loop* for executing `bar()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rewrite this logic in the following way: move exception handling into the loop and on each iteration check if you need to login:

```
needs_login = True

while True:

    try:

        if needs_login:
            login_to_system()
            needs_login = False

        query()
        calculate()
        update()

    except SomeNetworkException:
        needs_login = True

    except OtherExceptions:
        pass
```